# What is the best way to change the border-color of a bootstrap table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap table class.
The default border color is grey/silver - I think.

But I want to change the border-color to **red**, but I couldn't get it to work.

This is what I have
[image]

---

## CSS

```
.table {
border: red solid 1px !important;
}
```

---

## HTML : Table

```
<table class="table table-bordered piechart-key ">

    <thead >
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th> Item Summary</th>
        <th> Item List</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="30"></td>
            <td width="200">
                &gt; 50% of students answered these items correctly
            </td>
            <td width="50">5/25</td>
            <td width="100">5,10,15,19,23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30"></td>
            <td width="200">50% up to 75% of students answered these items correctly</td>
            <td width="50">8/25</td>
            <td width="100">3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30"></td>
            <td width="200">&ge; 75% of students answered these items correctly</td>
            <td width="50">12/25</td>
            <td width="100">1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here is my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/w0b73dwt/4/)

---

**What is the best way to change the border-color of a bootstrap table ?**

Comment: Just be a tad more specific with your CSS selectors and you'll be fine with what you've got!

Answer (score 6):

Try to apply it to the cells:

```
.table td{
    border: red solid 1px !important;
}
```

For the header:

```
.table th{
    border: red solid 1px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w0b73dwt/7/

---

EDIT

OBS: I used the **!important** directive 'cause I didn't find other simple way to do it. Of course, we all know it is a bad css practice, but in some cases we'll have to run the risk.
**Other way** would be to find exactly how bootstrap declares its style and create a css selector with higher priority for **td** and **th**. In this case this could break at the first bootstrap update.

Comment: @开发人员 take a look. See if the "!important" is really needded. I didn't play much with the styles.

Comment: It works with the `!important` . Without that, it's not working.

Comment: @ihue Same for me. For some reason, it does not work without !important (even when _Chrome Dev Tools_ does not show any superceding property)